# ZendFramework 2 tutorial Post Title:getTitle() Fatal Error

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Everything until now worked perfectly. I'm on page: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/understanding-routing.html.

On this page I had to modify 3 files:

-module.config.php

-detail.phtml

-ListController.php

I get the following error:

> Post Details
>
> Post Title
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function getTitle() on null in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\path\to\zf2-tutorial\module\Blog\view\blog\list\detail.phtml on line 6

I didn't paste the code, because it's the same from the link. Can you guys help me figure out my problem?

public function detailAction()

```
{
    $id = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');

    try {
        $post = $this->postService->findPost($id);
    } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $ex) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'post' => $post
    ));
}
```

Comment: Kinda broad... If you did what the tutorial says, it should work. If it doesn't, maybe you forgot something. You have to read it again and check if you did everything said...

Comment: I triple-checked.I don't think the error is on my part. I'm afraid the tutorial is faulty.

Comment: We need to see your code in the detailAction of the DetailController. Depending on where you are in the tutorial you have different outcomes. In part one, where I suspect you are, you should in fact get an Exception alas a different one.

Comment: I've edited the initial post and added the detailAction.But as I said in the initial post it's the same as on their website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the update. Now that I see where you are in the tutorial I think you have a problem in the Mapper. See the previous page and chapter [**Finishing the Mapper**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/zend-db-sql-zend-stdlib-hydrator.html#finishing-the-mapper)

If your mapper cannot find an article it should throw an error as seen in that code example on line 63. Obviously your mapper returns `null` which causes the error you see `Call to a member function getTitle() on null`. Because null is not an object after all and doesn't have a getTitle() function.

So have a look at the `ZendDbSqlMapper` class and the `find($id)` method and make sure it throws an error if an id isn't found.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I can't believe I made such a dumb mistake. I am fairly new to this framework, and PHP in general and this is all new and confusing stuff. If I'm not bugging you too much, can you please suggest me a way to learn this stuff easier ? like a website or something. This Zend  tutorial is kinda confusing. Thank you very much again.

Comment: @John94 Overall I think the tutorial is pretty good. Learning PHP with ZF2 is maybe not the best way. I suggest try Slim Framework first, it will teach you a few basics first. Then look at Laravel and finally maybe ZF. Or Symfony or CodeIgniter.